# Question about the KMP pattern matching algorithm

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching, computer-science, string-matching

I have a question about the KMP pattern matching algorithm. Below is a code snippet for calculating the `next` array:

```
int GetNext(char ch[], int length, int next[]) {
    next[1] = 0;
    int i = 1, j = 0;
    while (i < length) {
        if (j == 0 || ch[i] == ch[j])
            next[++i] = ++j;
        else
            j = next[j];
    }
}
```

I understand the principle of this code as follows: Let's assume we want to determine next[j+1], and we already know next[1], next[2],...next[j]. If next[j] = p, this means that the longest common prefix and suffix before the jth character of the string has a length of p-1. If the jth character of the string is equal to its pth character, then next[j+1] = p+1. Otherwise, we need to consider next[p], and if next[p] = k, we compare the jth character of the string with its kth character.

My question is, why don't we compare the jth character of the string with its (p-1)th character? How can we be sure that comparing the jth character of the string with its pth character is definitely not the correct answer? For instance, consider the following string (where numbers in S1 are indices):

S1S2S3 S4S5S6 S7S8S9 S10 S11

Using the algorithm above to compute next[11], we can determine that S1S2S3S4 and S7S8S9S10 are the longest common prefix and suffix for S11. My question is, how can we be certain of this? How can we be sure that S1S2S3S4S5 and S6S7S8S9S10 are not the longest common prefix and suffix for S11?

I want to understand the details of this algorithm; this question has been bothering me for a while